# Unique sorting scenario

Tags: php, mysql, sorting

I have a mysql database with player statistics.

playerid | player | points | league

I would like to sort a query on points DESC, but some players have played in other leagues, so they have multiple records in the DB.

Ideally, I would like to sort on points in "Major League", and when a player has played in other leagues, list those below. It should look something like this:

```
John Smith | 27 | Major League
Gary White | 24 | Major League
           | 32 | Minors
Joe Flatts | 15 | Major League
```

ETC...

I'm not sure if it's easier to create this in a MySQL view or server-side in my PHP.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in SQL by joining up to second copy of the players table (filtering only the major league), but it's not great for larger sizes of tables:

```
SELECT l.*, (l.league = 'Major League') AS major
FROM league_points AS l 
    LEFT JOIN league_points AS major 
        ON l.player = major.player AND major.league = 'Major League'
ORDER BY major.points DESC, major DESC, league DESC
```

You probably want to remove the major column from your output, it's just there to ensure that the major league comes first in the ORDER BY operation.  If you don't want players who haven't played in the major league to turn up at all, change the LEFT JOIN to just an INNER JOIN.

Comment: The table will never be more than 50-60 records. When I try your SQL in Navicat, I get "View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause"...When I try it as a query in php I get "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE league = 'MINOR' ORDER BY p DESC ) AS ordered ON l.player = ord' at line 5"

Comment: That error is because that particular DB doesn't allow nested queries. You need that nesting because you're trying to sort rows based on information that isn't always in the rows (i.e., if the league was "minor" then you need to get the points for that player in the major league).

Comment: Scratch that - I think I've got it figured out. One second. Let me test it out!

Comment: I've just realized that you don't have to nest that query.  I've edited it abuse the join clause to select only the major league.

Comment: Sure enough! Your last edit cleaned it up nicely. Thanks for your help!